# Adding logins when you have more than one gmail account

Tags: support, user-accounts, login, openid

I have another computer that is associated with a different gmail account. I will be taking this computer with me to Georgia for the weekend but it auto logins in as a different user that was just created. When I go to my logins in order to add this other gmail, it doesn't work when I click add a login using Google. It just goes back to my user page since I am logged in with Google already. How do I associate two Google email accounts on SE?

[image]

I tried @Najib suggestion of using another login to associate the two Google accounts; however, when I click add login and Google, it just says log me in and it leads to a loop of login in and out but never adding the account.

Can a moderator get involved to help resolve this issue?

Now I have progressed to a hybrid account merger. I can be logged on with one Google account on the main page of Health and the other when I go to the meta page. This is my profile on Health when I am on the main page:

[image]

You will notice at the top my rep matches my profile rep. If I go the meta page, you will see the rep of the Google account I can't merge of 1 and my rep of 121.

[image]

When I am on the main page, I am logged in with one Google account, and if I go to meta, I am logged in as the other account. How about some help? I know these images are from a different SE, but I already have the question up here and this behavior doesn't happen anywhere else as of yet.

Comment: I found this, but it is closed as a duplicate of a deleted question: [How to manage stack overflow open ID if you have two Google accounts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75084/how-to-manage-stack-overflow-open-id-if-you-have-two-google-accounts)

Comment: @martin where is the option to add openid? I don't see it on the profile page. Also, the dupe it was closed as has been deleted.

Comment: I don't see it, either. But on the network profile I see something called *"my logins"*.

Comment: Maybe this would be a better link: [Two logins from same openid](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139981/two-logins-from-same-openid)

Comment: And [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/159832/259867) is an answer by an SE developer, pointing out to an issue specifically with multiple Google logins.

Comment: Sorry to ask the obvious, but did you try logging off and then logging on again? I recall being able to select the Google account to use when logging on to SE.

Comment: @Woodface I followed the instructions. When I get to the last step it says to enter my openid, I don't have an openid I was hoping to create one. I don't see how to do this from those instructions.

Comment: For some reason the [login page on stackexchange.com is different](http://stackexchange.com/users/login?noauto=true) (there is an additional login option "login with SE"), if you try from that page does it work?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi when I click add account, Google, it allows me to select the other account, but then it says do you want to logout and login with this account. It never adds it. No matter which one I try it is just a loop of logging on and off without adding.

Comment: I think the idea is that you should create another openid (like Yahoo, Facebook, whatever), link it to your account, log out of your old google account, log in with your new openid provider on SE, and then link the new google account. I don't know if it's the most efficient path but it should work.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I will have to full around with this when I am back in NH.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi doesn't work. I just tried using a yahoo account that is associated with one Google account. What I did was logged on with Yahoo and then tried to associate the other Google account but it just signs me on as it.

Comment: Then I don't know, sorry.